# Force phonegap disconnect

Tags: extjs, cordova, sencha-touch

I need to test the online and offline events written in my app. I'm testing the app through my browser so I'd like some code that simulates a disconnect from the internet in phonegap. As in forcing it to go offline then back online, client side. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already tried use [PhoneGap Emulation](http://emulate.phonegap.com/)? There is a lot of features.

You can also test directly on device. Android logcat can receive the console.log of browser. I belive this works with xcode too.